# jQuery ajaxComplete callback execution order

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to get the ajaxComplete callback to be called prior to the individual ajax request callbacks?  I want ajaxComplete to be called prior to any of the success callbacks on an ajax request.

EDIT:  Added psuedo-code.

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(_e, xhr, _settings) {
    alert("This happens after the callbacks for any particular ajax request, but I want it to be executed first");
});

$.ajax("/my-test-endpoint", {
    success: function(data) {
        alert("I happen before the ajaxComplete callback");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not getting what you mean here. Could you please share some pseudo-code regarding this to explain the requirement in a better way.

Comment: @palaѕн I have edited my original post with the requested pseudo-code.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because as per the event order [shown here](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) `ajaxComplete` is always called after all local events. Only the `ajaxStart` is executed first.

Comment: @palaѕн thank you for that link.  That's exactly what I was trying to find and couldn't get the right search terms.